# NSString's boundingRect function misleading behavior

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

When I was trying to wrap up into box with by means of NSString function boundingRect with paying attention to initial Insets (8,0,8,0), so I tried to calculate each frame of my text with:

```
let size = CGSize(width:250 ,height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin.union(.usesFontLeading)

        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18
            )], context: nil)
```

Then when I creating my text's frame

```
cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRect(x: 48 + 8, y: 0, width: estimatedFrame.width , height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
```

[image]

It cuts my text. Even there is no default padding and insets in width. 
but when I just added arbitrary number to the width parameter I wraps full text properly. [image]

Does someone know the real reason of this behavior? Even more I can add to width parameter not 16 points even less like 8.3425 points and it will work properly but if i pass 8.3424 it won't? Doesn't boundingRect func should provide already suitable dimensions for my wrap box?

Answer (score 1):

`UITextView` has insets that cannot display text (note that the text does not start where the gray background starts). If you just set the width of the view, the actual space for the text is limited by those insets.

See `UITextView.textContainerInsets`. You need to add them to the width and height of the frame you are setting.

Comment: I've mentioned above about default insets I already knew about it so because I added 20 point in the height parameter because there default inset 8 pixels BUT there is no default inset in the width parameter according to textContainerInsets default values